# How to dynamically set object's property based on prop name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, reflection, visual-studio-2015

I hope it will be clear what I want to do.

I want to fetch data from database based on properties of provided object and then fill those properties with the retrieved data.
So, if for example a user defines a class

```
class Person
{
   public:
      int Id;
      string Name;
};
```

and then when he calls `MyDatabase.Instance.ExecQuery<Person>()` it should return `Person` object filled with information.

What I did is: a user should define the class as following:

```
class Person : public DBEntity
{
    ENTITIY_PROP(Person , int, Id)
    ENTITIY_PROP(Person , string, Name)
};
```

The defined macros ensure to add the name and type of the properties to `_propsMeta`.
Now, how do I set object's property based on it's name (see `ExecQuery`)?

**MY INITIAL SOLUTION**
I though to add `map` that maps property to a function that sets the property but I cannot have a `map` of references to functions with different signatures. Any ideas? If you think I need to change my design to accomplish what I need - let me know.

```
template <typename T>
void ExecQuery()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<DBEntity, T>(), "a Class should inherit from DBEntity");

    const auto& props = entity->GetPropsMeta();
    auto row = GetData(props);
    T entity = new T();
    for (const auto& colName : row.Columns)
    {
        string val = row[colName];
        // TODO: SET ENTITY'S PROPERTY colName with val
    }
}

#define ENTITIY_PROP(Class, Type, Name) \
        private: \
            int _##Name; \
        public: \
            class Property_##Name { \
            public: \
                Property_##Name(Class* parent) : _parent(parent) \
                { \
                    _parent->SetPropMeta(#Name, #Type); \
                } \
                Type operator = (Type value) \
                { \
                    _parent->Set##Name(value); \
                    return _parent->Get##Name(); \
                } \
                operator Type() const \
                { \
                    return static_cast<const Class*>(_parent)->Get##Name(); \
                } \
                Property_##Name& operator =(const Property_##Name& other) \
                { \
                    operator=(other._parent->Get##Name()); return *this; \
                }; \
                Property_##Name(const Property_##Name& other) = delete; \
            private: \
                Class* _parent; \
            } Name { this }; \
            \
            Type Get##Name() const { return _##Name; } \
            void Set##Name(int value) { _##Name = value; } \

    class DBEntity
    {
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> _propsMeta;

    public:
        const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& GetPropsMeta() { return _propsMeta; }    
    };
```

Comment: Yes, you can't have map of functions of different signature - you need to have some kind of type erasure. The most simple solution is just to have std::any or boost::any as argument.

Comment: Do you absolutely want the user to create the Person class like this: `class Person { ENTITY_PROP(Person, int, Id), ENTITY_PROP(Person, string, Name)};`? Or would this work as well? `MAKE_CLASS(Person, (int, Id), (string, Name))`? I have an idea how to help you but it would require using the latter form.

Comment: You might look at [boost::hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection-json) which allows introspection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using boost::hana:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/define_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/for_each.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

// for simplicity I assume that a row is an unordered_map
using row_type = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;

// this is how your users will be defining classes
struct Person {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
    (int, Id),
    (std::string, Name));
};

struct Car {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Car,
    (std::string, Brand),
    (int, HorsePower));
};


// convenient function to extract the row's mapped value and set it directly to the target
template <class T>
void set_data(T& target, std::string key, const row_type& row)
{
    target = boost::lexical_cast<T>(row.at(key));
}


// this is what your database will be doing
template <class Entity>
Entity extract(const row_type& row)
{
    Entity entity;

    // accessors provides a tuple of pairs, where the first element of each pair is a "compile-time" string from which you can extract the key
    // and the second element is a function which returns a reference to appropriate member
    hana::for_each(hana::accessors<Entity>(), [&entity, &row](auto unit)
    {
        std::string property_name = hana::to<const char*>(hana::first(unit));
        set_data(hana::second(unit)(entity), property_name, row);
    });

    return entity;
}

// and now test it
int main()
{
    auto person = extract<Person>({{"Id", "42"},{"Name", "John"}});
    std::cout << person.Id << " " << person.Name << std::endl;

    auto car = extract<Car>({{"Brand", "BMW"},{"HorsePower", "95"}});
    std::cout << car.Brand << " " << car.HorsePower << std::endl;

}
```

You should have a careful read at the relevant functions in the [documentation page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I tried to add the boost header on "Visual Studio 2015 Update 3", but I get errors of c++14 compatibility. I tried to add "/std:c++14" but I still get error. Does it only works on VS2017?

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio at all. You just need a C++14 compiler (I am using g++)